# Regular Expression: Help Matching a number less than 24

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

so I'm making this regular expression to verify some text boxes on a website that I'm designing for an internship.

The problem is that I'm not so keen on regular expressions, and I'm close to having a working one that matches a number between *0-24* and no more than two decimal places.

This is what I have so far. The pattern is also matching any string; such as, `"a"` or `"az"`.

```
var pattern = "^([0-9]{0,2}?.?[0-9]{0,2}|1[0-9].?[0-9]{0,2}|2[0-4].?[0-9]{0,2})$";
```

Comment: Why would you do this with regex.. 
You can, of course, if you want to, but this seems easy enough to solve without regex. :-)

Comment: @DylanMeeus Perhaps OP wants to use the HTML5 input pattern attribute? Apart from that, I would also recommend a more readable alternative.

Comment: @le_m  Yes!  that's exactly what I'm using it for in combination with some angular to display warnings to the user when they've input something incorrectly.

Comment: What is this "a" or "az" that you have mentioned. Please specify what you want the regex to do entirely.

Comment: @2manyints How about <input type="number"> with respective boundaries as an alternative?

Comment: `a` and `az` are matched because `.` matches any symbol but a newline.

Comment: @le_m The problem with using input type = "number" is that I had to add some custom CSS to disable the spinner on the righthand side. That alongside some CSS that came with the application made is annoying to handle because I was overwriting some project specifications.

Comment: @10100111001 I want it to match any number between 0 - 24 with no more than two decimal places.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, I guess I misread the question and thought OP wanted the field to match "a" and "az" somehow.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So... how does match the literal string interpretation of a "." instead of a JavaScript interpreted period in a regular expression.

Comment: See ndn's answer, that is enough. Dot must be escaped. Or place it into a character class.

Answer (score 6):

To get a number between 0 and 24 (24 excluded) with optional up to two decimal places:

```
^(\d|1\d|2[0-3])(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

---

The decimal part:

- `\.` - match the decimal dot
- `\d{1,2}` - one or two digits
- `()?` - makes it optional

---

The whole part:

- `\d` - numbers 0-9
- `1\d` - numbers 10-19
- `2[0-3]` - numbers 20-23
- `(x|y|z)` - one of `x`, `y` or `z`

---

As for the *"why is my version matching things like `"a"` and `"az"` part"* - it's a little complex, but it basically boils down to you using dots (like `.?`). In regex, a dot means *"any one character"*. To make it match a literal dot, you need to escape it with a slash just like I did.

---

**Minor remark**: If you want optional leading zero for single digit numbers, replace `1\d` with `[01]\d`. If you want mandatory leading zero for single digit numbers, replace `\d|1\d` with `[01]\d`. If you don't want leading zeroes, leave it as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the quick explanation! Your answer is much more readable than mine!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you do not want 05 or 5.50

```
^((?:[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(?:\.(?:[1-9]|[0-9][1-9]))?)$
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/oE3gK1/1)

Answer (score 1):

To get a integer number between 1 and 23: `^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])$`

Answer (score 0):

The following is a quick attempt to match a floating point number from 0 to 24.99 with up to two non-zero digits

```
^(([0-9])|([01][0-9])|(2[0-4]))(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

I think it might be easier to use math to do this though...

Comment: So why do you need to match the `24-24.99` range given that the question is *"Help Matching a number less than 24"*?

Answer (score 0):

You can see the explanation of the entire regex as well as test it out [here](https://regex101.com/r/yW8rP2/2). I have also added a few test cases.

```
^(\d|[01]\d|2[0-3])(\.\d{1,2})?$
```

Test cases:

```
Valid:
   22
   1.29
   2.99
   9.99
   13.24
   17.38
   20.01
   02.15
   15.35
   23.56
   1.1

Invalid:
   24.29
   235.215
   21.256
```

Comment: Yes, 04 is still more than 0 and less than 24. Some people do enter 0 before single digits to avoid errors in highly critical systems.

Comment: But we don't want more than 2 digits before the decimal.

Comment: Added the test cases which should clarify that.